# React Native fetch operation completes only when I tap the device's screen

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I am working with React Native, running on a device and JS debugging with chrome developer tools' console.

I have a signUp method which returns a fetch promise (ES6):

```
signUp(username, password) {
 ...
return fetch(USER_URL, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: headers,
  body:body
})
.then((response) => {
  return response.json();
}).then((response) => {
  return this.login(username, password);
});
```

Login is:

```
login(username, password) {
  ...

  return fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers
  })
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
}
```

Now when I invoke it:

```
return this.signUp(username, password)
  .then((response) => {

    console.log("I am here");

  });
```

For some reason the "I am here" message is not shown until I tap the screen of the device. Any idea why?